# How many AES 128-bit keys does a MIFARE PLUS tag have?

Tags: encryption, aes, authentication

I know that the question is a bit silly but I dont know **how many keys can a MIFARE PLUS tag store in it.**

Provided that I have a MIFARE PLUS S tag with 4k memory room and the key length is 128 bit, then the maximum amount of keys stored will be 31. 
(4000/128 = 31.25 rounded to 31)

It is correct ? The product leaflet doesn't tips how many keys are or if its is more then one.( I am assuming that its so)

Hugs,

Comment: Apart from being pure calculation unrelated to cryptography, you're probably confusing bits and bytes.

Comment: Then it could have 250 AES128bit keys ?

Comment: It could if it stores nothing other than keys. But anyway, you should contact MIFARE technical support for better info, we Crypto.SE is just a third party not having much to do with them.